# IPhone: How to put UITextField and UITableView on same View? recomended way

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I am new to IOS development. I want to create the view like the shown in Pic.

I also want that when user write in textfield and Keyboard appears TextField scrollup to Keyboard and should be hidden behind Key board.

[image]
thanks, Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use a `UITableViewController` but a standard view controller and implement `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` and implement the necessary delegate methods in your controller, like `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

This will allow you to have a table view and control it like you would with a `UITableViewController` and have any other interface elements you wish.

Comment: Of course you can use a UITableViewController - a UITableViewController can respond to the delegate and datasource just as easily as using any other view controller...

Comment: Yes you can, but you can't any other layout elements on the interface besides the table view, this just gives a little more freedom to make more complex interfaces.

Comment: @MweyaMutsvene What he means is that if you use a UITableViewController in your storyboard, you can't add additional controls in Interface Builder. You can add the search bar to the header (or footer, I think) of the table view, but if you wanted anything else, say above/outside the table view for example, you have to change your view controller type to a standard UIViewController and then IB will allow you to add all of the controls you're interested in displaying. His response has nothing to do with whether it would support delegate and datasource.

Comment: Sorry, now that you explain it that way, that makes sense - I was under the impression that you were saying you couldn't create the view in the image the poster added to his question in a UITableViewController.

Comment: Yes, you can, but others have given that option already, so I decided to give another option that will let him do that and also offer more freedom if he ever attempts a more complex interface with a table view.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to add the textfield and button inside of the footer.  You can use keyboard notifications to move the view offset so that your textfield will be visible when the user is typing in the keyboard.

Footer:
*I'm assuming the textfield and send button are ivars.

```
// add footer to table
UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 85.0f)];
if(yourTextField ==nil){
     yourTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,200,35)];
}
if(yourSendButton ==nil){
     yourSendButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225,5,75,35)];
     yourSendButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sendBtnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}


[footerView addSubview:yourTextField];
[footerView addSubview:yourSendButton];
[tableView setTableFooterView:footerView];
```

Here is some example code for  moving the view for the keyboard:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSValue *keyboardFrameValue = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [[self view] convertRect:[keyboardFrameValue CGRectValue] fromView:nil];
    NSNumber *duration = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:[duration floatValue] animations:^{
        [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.origin.x,
                                        scrollView.frame.origin.y, 
                                        scrollView.frame.size.width, 
                                        keyboardFrame.origin.y - scrollView.frame.origin.y)];

    }];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSNumber *duration = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:[duration floatValue] animations:^{
        [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.origin.x,
                                        scrollView.frame.origin.y, 
                                        scrollView.frame.size.width, 
                                        self.view.frame.size.height - (iPhone ? 44.0f : 0.0f))];
    }];
}
```

Comment: I believe the question deals with adding a section footer, not a table footer.

Comment: in that case just place the footerview insde of the correct footer for section, using `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section` just return the footer at the end of the method.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement the UITableView's delegate methods:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

an example of adding a textfield to the footer would look something like:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
  UIView* footer = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)] autorelease];
  footer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  UITextField* field = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)] autorelease];
  [field setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleBezel];
  [footer addSubview:field];
  return footer;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
  return 44;
}
```

To get the keyboard will respond properly automatically - you just just need to resign the textfield when you are done with it.